# How to set text area to maximum width in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a chat area. It'll display the messages on top and the input on the bottom. I want to keep the "esc" button and "send" button the same width, but increase the textarea to maximum width while keeping all three elements inline. This is what I've tried so far.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="chatArea">
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="userInput">
        <button id="endChat" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Esc</button>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="messageArea"></textarea>
        </div> 

        <button id="sendMessage" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#chatArea {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
}

#messageArea {
    width: 322px;
}

#endChat, #sendMessage {
    width: 70px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

But this is the result (didn't show the full chatArea div, only the bottom).

[image: the problem]

So how can we make it so the textArea resizes itself to be of maximum width while the 3 elements (esc, textArea, and send) are inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
    <form role="form" id="userInput">
        <button id="endChat" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Esc</button>
        <button id="sendMessage" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="messageArea"></textarea>
        </div> 
    </form>
```

Note the order of `#endChat`, `#sendMessage` and `.form-group` elements.

CSS:

```
#endChat {
  float: left;
}

#sendMessage {
  float: right;
}

.form-group {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#messageArea {
   width: 100%;
}

#endChat, #sendMessage {
  height: 110px;
}
```

Comment: dude, the text area is smaller now, theres a huge gap between it and the send button,

Comment: the #messageArea didn't change anything bro

Comment: it only works on regular css and html, I'm using bootstrap

Comment: The problem in using `form-inline` class on `form`. Just remove it and things will work.

Comment: thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

When using bootstrap I suggest to try formatting the bootstrap classes in css. Often the bootstrap formatting overrides your own css file unless you override them in your own css-file. Try this:

```
#endChat {
  float: left;
}

#sendMessage {
  float: right;
}

.form-group {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.form-control#messageArea{
   width: 100%;
}

#endChat, #sendMessage {
  height: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove following code from your css:

```
#messageArea {
    width: 322px;
}
```

form-control class of textarea will auto resize its width to 100% of the area.